# Eclipse Scala IDE - Worksheet process has terminated unexpectedly

Tags: eclipse, scala

I get this error on my new installation of Scala IDE (Eclipse) for Linux anytime I try to use scala worksheets:

```
Worksheet process has terminated unexpectedly (exit code 143)
At the time of termination, the following text was available in the output streams:
Standard output:

Standard error
```

Does anybody know what's happening? I'm using java-7-openjdk

Thanks!

Comment: what is the scala version?

Comment: I'm on 2.11.7, Thanks. Also, this is the scala-ide I.m using: Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK

Build id: 4.3.0-vfinal-2015-12-01T15:55:22Z-Typesafe